# Unix - Uncomment xml comments

Tags: xml, linux, unix, sed

I have below node from XML file. How do I uncomment the first occurrance of mainHost using Unix shell script or commands?

```
        <!-- Host without authentication -->
            <!-- <mainHost> <hostName>test.com</hostName> <httpPort>80</httpPort>
                    </mainHost> -->
            <!-- Host with authentication userId: User name of Host server Password:
                     -->
            <!-- <mainHost> <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName> <httpPort>80</httpPort>
                    <userId>username</userId> <password>password</password>
                    </mainHost> -->
```

I have tried with below command with different variations but that does not seem to work.

sed '0,/<!-- /{s/<!-- //}' /test.xml

I am expecting below output

```
        <!-- Host without authentication -->
             <mainHost> <hostName>test.com</hostName> <httpPort>80</httpPort>
                    </mainHost> 
            <!-- Host with authentication userId: User name of Host server Password:
                     -->
            <!-- <mainHost> <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName> <httpPort>80</httpPort>
                    <userId>username</userId> <password>password</password>
                    </mainHost> -->
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no difference between both examples.

Comment: Sorry, corrected expected output, also the entire sed command is not posted but any help would be great

Comment: Any ideas how this can be done please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track (under the assumption that `sed` has to be used).

Create a file (for example `script.sed`) with the following content:

```
0,/<\/mainHost>/{
  /<mainHost>/,/<\/mainHost>/{
    s/<!--//
    s/-->//
  }
}
```

and run `sed -f script.sed FILE.xml`.

Note that this solution is difficult to generalize. `sed` may not be the best tool for the task.

Comment: Hi werkritter, if sed is not the right tool, is there a better option to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried this solution and it didn't work. Any thoughts please?

Comment: Solutions based on regular expressions are not the best way to parse and change XML files — they tend to be fragile and hard to expand. For example, if you would like to uncomment the second occurrence of `mainHost`, the `sed` script would be considerably more complicated.

The better way to work with XML is to use some markup processing tools and libraries available in major programming languages. For example, in Python you can choose between `xml.sax`, `xml.dom` and `xml.etree`.

Unfortunately, I'm not too knowledgeable with regard to these tools.

Comment: As to the script not working: from the above script I prepared a `sed` oneliner: `sed '0,/<\/mainHost>/{/<mainHost>/,/<\/mainHost>/{s/<!--//;s/-->//}}' file.xml` Please try it out. For the reference, I used GNU `sed`, version 4.2.2.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This is helpful. I will write a script in Python to fix this. I am using Redhat and the sed command does not work there.